# How do I use RelayState from SAML to specifiy landing page at the SP, using saml-omniauth and devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, saml, omniauth

How do I use RelayState from SAML protocol to specify the landing page at SP in IdP initiated SSO ?

I have set an IdP initiated SSO process between IdP and SP. It works but it lands at root_path. I need this to land at RelayState URL.

I am using devise. Find below my controller:

```
def saml
    student = Student.where(email: request.env["omniauth.auth"]['uid'].to_s).first
    if student
      sign_in_and_redirect student, event: :authentication
    else
        flash[:error] = t 'flash_msg.access_1'
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to substitute `sign_in_and_redirect method by sign_in method` only. Then redirect user to RelayState URL by doing `redirect_to params[:RelayState]`. Final saml method is:

```
  def saml
    student = Student.where(email: request.env["omniauth.auth"]['uid'].to_s).first
    if student
      sign_in student, event: :authentication
      redirect_to params[:RelayState]
    else
        flash[:error] = t 'flash_msg.access_1'
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I hope it helps someone !

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but how are you setting `RelayState` in the params here?

Comment: @DougEdey the `RelayState` is either set by the IdP or passed to the IdP in the initial SAML request.